# Barplot along Latitude

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am sure there are similar questions to this one already, but I couldn't find the solution.

I am trying to make a stacked barplot for this data set

```
 Lat         A           B          C
  1: -73.8138 0.9880964 0.011903579 0.00000000
  2: -72.9227 0.9944572 0.005542802 0.00000000
  3: -72.9227 0.9929407 0.007059293 0.00000000
  4: -72.9227 0.9947268 0.005273249 0.00000000
  5: -72.8023 0.9955415 0.004458509 0.00000000
 ---                                          
399: -43.5885 0.2454905 0.726201943 0.02830751
400: -43.5885 0.2487154 0.723154998 0.02812957
401: -43.2388 0.3764078 0.609685743 0.01390649
402: -42.3151 0.5688570 0.415558063 0.01558497
403: -41.2581 0.4352897 0.526782296 0.03792798
```

I would like to show the bars along Latitude (it is possible that some Lats are duplicated because associated with different Longitudes).

I tried this

```
df.melt <- melt(df,
                  id.vars = "Lat",
                  variable.name = "class",
                  value.name = "fraction")


ggplot(df.melt, aes(x=Lat, y=fraction, fill=class))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme_bw()
```

however, it does not show any bar.

so I tried this other way:

```
df$number <- rownames(df)
df.melt <- melt(df[,-"Lat"],
                id.vars = "number",
                variable.name = "class",
                value.name = "fraction")


ggplot(df.melt, aes(x=number, y=fraction, fill=class))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme_bw()
```

but the x label is not properly ordered.

How can I plot df along Lat?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Lat) %>% 
  mutate(Lat = as.factor(Lat)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Lat, y=value, fill=name))+
  geom_col()+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]